# Error sending JSON in POST request body with request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have this POST request with request.js:

```
request.post({
    uri: "https://app.bom.com/app/search/savedSearch",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    jar: jar,
    json: true,
    body: {
      "objectType" : "items",
      "name": "",
      "defaultSearch": false,
      "criteriaRows": [{
        "id": 0,
        "value": {
          "name": "item_number",
          "dataType": "string",
          "operator": "2",
          "value": "161225",
          "value1": ""
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

The request always comes out error; whereas, if I disable `json: true` and use `JSON.stringify` on the body, then the request came back with the result I wanted. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What's the error? What does the server return? What status did the server return?

Comment: shouldn't the `body :{}` be actually `data : { }` where data request params  that we pass to server

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set the headers if you use the `json` property, and if you put your object directly into the `json` property, it will be sent as the body.

```
  request.post({
    uri: "https://app.bom.com/app/search/savedSearch",
    jar: jar,
    json: {
      "objectType" : "items",
      "name": "",
      "defaultSearch": false,
      "criteriaRows": [{
        "id": 0,
        "value": {
          "name": "item_number",
          "dataType": "string",
          "operator": "2",
          "value": "161225",
          "value1": ""
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set to `json:true` it tries to parse you response as JSON. check if your response is a json